# How Tabu Search is used to solve Travelling Purchaser

Tags: algorithm, np-hard, tabu-search

It is very often to see that Tabu Search is used to solve the travelling purchaser / travelling salesman, I would like to look into it but always cant figure out the progression and the stop condition, can anyone do a explanation on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

The stop condition is usually time given to solve it.

Progression is moves like [2-opt (TailChainSwapMove)](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#tailChainSwapMoveSelector), [relocate (ChainedChangeMove)](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#changeMoveSelector), [swap (ChainedSwapMove)](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#swapMoveSelector), subchain change/swap, ...

And those moves are applied in a typical Local Search - more specifically Tabu Search - fashion:

[image: Tabu Search OptaPlanner]